WordPress redirection in .htaccess makes 404 error
I'll turn crazy :
I've some urls https://example.com/events-a_city-a_zipcode that must be redirected to htttps://example.com/events/?city=a_city&zipcode=a_zipcode WITHOUT changing the visible url.
The "basic"  one :
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/events-([^/]+)-([0-9]+)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^events-([^/]+)-([0-9]+)$ /events/?city=$1&zipcode=$2 [QSA,L]

[+ standard wordpress htacces rules]

gives me an error 404.
The same rule when adding R=301 in [QSA,L] works (but the redirection is visible...).
I've also test rules like :
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^events-([^/-]+(?:-[^/-]+)*)-([0-9]{5})/?$ /events/ [QSA,E=VILLE:$1,E=CP:$2]

RewriteCond %{ENV:VILLE} .+
RewriteCond %{ENV:CP} .+
RewriteRule ^events/$ /events/?ville=%{ENV:VILLE}&cp=%{ENV:CP} [QSA,L]

[+ standard wordpress htacces rules]

with the same 404 error...
In fact, I've tried dozens of rules without success.
Can you help me please ?

Why so complicated? https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=4c48bc35-2cfe-406d-972c-bed55745c82a

You're right akarsha, It's one of the many attempts I've done.
The problem remains the same :
RewriteRule ^/?events-([^-]+)-(\d+)/?$ /events/?city=$1&zipcode=$2 [QSA,L] => 404
RewriteRule ^/?events-([^-]+)-(\d+)/?$ /events/?city=$1&zipcode=$2 [R=302,QSA,L] => OK
Important info : the website is running WordPress

"The same rule when adding R=301 in [QSA,L] works " - AFAIK, WordPress determines the requested URL by looking into $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] - but that value does not change due to internal URL rewrites. So even though you rewrote the URL internally, it will still be looking for a post with the slug events-a_city-a_zipcode in the database. You should really rather try and do this from within WP, using add_rewrite_rule.
